# Problemas con saltos en línea con un archivo json generado por php

Tags: php, json

Estoy queriendo hacer una consulta a una base de datos y generando dicha consulta en un archivo json mediante la función `json_encode( )` de php.

El problema que tengo es que al principio del archivo o de la cadena generada. Me aparece unos saltos en líneas que ya intentando con *str_replace* y varias formas no he podido quitar.

El archivo que me genera es el siguiente

```
[{"title":"FutbolParaguayo","image":"https:\/\/www.futbolparaguayoenvivo.com\/IPTV\/images\/85193_6--2522293-Flag Of Paraguay.jpg","provider":"webview","arguments":["https:\/\/www.futbolparaguayoenvivo.com\/elegir-calidad\/"]}]
```

Cuando debería quedar solo así:

```
[{"title":"FutbolParaguayo","image":"https:\/\/www.futbolparaguayoenvivo.com\/IPTV\/images\/85193_6--2522293-Flag Of Paraguay.jpg","provider":"webview","arguments":"[https:\/\/www.futbolparaguayoenvivo.com\/elegir-calidad\/]"}]
```

Ya intente de todo y no puedo deshacerme de los saltos en línea.

```
<?php
header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );
include("includes/connection.php");
 $file_path = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'/';     
    $jsonObj= array();  
        $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_channels
        LEFT JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_channels.cat_id= tbl_category.cid 
        WHERE tbl_channels.status=1 ORDER BY tbl_channels.id ASC";
        $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
        $row=array();
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            $row['title'] =$data['channel_title'];
            $row['image'] =$file_path.'images/'.$data['channel_thumbnail'];
            $row['provider'] =$data['channel_type'];
            $row['arguments'] = array($data['channel_url']);
   
            array_push($jsonObj,$row);
}
$set = $jsonObj;
$val= json_encode($set);
echo trim($val); 
die();
```

El archivo **`connection.php`**:

```
<?php 
         ob_start();
    session_start();
    
    //header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    
    
        if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="localhost" or $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="192.168.1.125")
        {   
            //local  

                 DEFINE ('DB_USER', '*****');
                 DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '******');
                 DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
                 DEFINE ('DB_NAME', '****');
        }
        else
        {
            //local live 

             DEFINE ('DB_USER', '*******');
             DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '*****');
             DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');           
             DEFINE ('DB_NAME', '****');
        }

    
    $mysqli =mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
    {
        echo "error al conectar con MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    mysqli_query($mysqli,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");    



    //datos
    $setting_qry="SELECT * FROM tbl_settings where id='1'";
    $setting_result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$setting_qry);
    $settings_details=mysqli_fetch_assoc($setting_result);

    define("ONESIGNAL_APP_ID",$settings_details['onesignal_app_id']);
    define("ONESIGNAL_REST_KEY",$settings_details['onesignal_rest_key']);
    
     define("APP_NAME",$settings_details['app_name']);
    define("APP_LOGO",$settings_details['app_logo']);
    define("APP_FROM_EMAIL",$settings_details['email_from']);

    define("API_LATEST_LIMIT",$settings_details['api_latest_limit']);
    define("API_CAT_ORDER_BY",$settings_details['api_cat_order_by']);
    define("API_CAT_POST_ORDER_BY",$settings_details['api_cat_post_order_by']);

    //Perfil
    if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
    {
        $profile_qry="SELECT * FROM tbl_admin where id='".$_SESSION['id']."'";
        $profile_result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$profile_qry);
        $profile_details=mysqli_fetch_assoc($profile_result);

        define("PROFILE_IMG",$profile_details['image']);
    }
    
     
?>
```

Comment: podrias incluir el resultado?? ya que no sabemos donde te genera el salto de linea!

Comment: Por favor, incluye en la pregunta todos los recursos necesarios para replicar el problema. Sin enlaces a sitios externos que, en el futuro, posiblemente no existan o rompan los enlaces por cambios en su funcionamiento.

Comment: Gracias ahora añado

Comment: no logró ver ninguna diferencia entre los dos json

Comment: @ReneLimon es el espacio en blanco y salto en linea al comienzo del la cadena .Fíjate bien

Comment: de momento elimina las variables llave y coloca  `$row['arguments'] = array($data['channel_url']);` y dale un `var_dump($val);`

Comment: en la ultima linea, intenta `echo trim($val);`

Comment: @Bryro ya elimine la llave. y coloque el array en su lugar da exactamente el mismo resultado. Al agregarle el var_dump($val)  me tira resultado lo mismo pero  string(227)  antes de la cadena. Pero igual sigue el salto en linea. :(

Comment: @ReneLimon lo probé y devuelve exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: intenta definiendo `$row=array()` antes del `while()`

Comment: Como quedaría el código me podes enviar? me perdí un poco ? Quedaría así ?  
                $row=array()
  while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql));

Comment: @Bryro porque hice eso y me devuelve lo mismo :(

Comment: Mira con el inspector de codigo del navegador a ver que te manda y activa los errores de php. Tambien agrega el contenido de connection.php a tu pregunta puede que de ahi venga el salto de linea!

Comment: No me muestra ningún error. El problema esta que lo leo desde una app de android y me crea problemas por el salto en linea. Ahora agrego connection.php para que lo mires.

Comment: el problema no está en este script, debe venir del lugar donde haces el llamado, aunque esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3725453/4987172) de SO en inglés dice que podría deberse a los espacios después de `?>` y antes de `<?php`

Comment: @ReneLimon realmente esta todo bien pero el salto de linea al principio del archivo es el problema. Al leerlo me genera errores. Probe guardando esa cadena sin el salto en linea en un archivo.json y lo leyó perfecto. El problema que tengo es ese salto en linea. Y ya probé absolutamente todo y no puedo eliminarlo.

Comment: Ve por partes colocando echo "*"; a ver donde se genera el salto de linea colocas en la primera linea imprimes y asi vas bajando el echo hasta llegar antes de while()

Comment: Incluí echo "*";  antes de include("includes/connection.php"); y me mostro antes del salto en linea. Y si coloco después del include ya se muestra abajo. Probablemente sea el include???  Alguna idea de que podria ser @Bryro

Comment: Lo pude solucionar era algo que por poco me llevo 4 días. En el archivo connection.php tenia dos saltos en linea al final de ?>. Saludos !

Comment: A que bueno! Aveces un simple echo ayuda mucho!

Answer (score 1):

PHP tiene la opción de *JSON_PRETTY_PRINT* desde 5.4.0 (fecha de lanzamiento 01 de marzo de 2012).

Esto debe funcionar:

```
$json = json_decode($string);
echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Fuente: https://www.iteramos.com/pregunta/66796/pretty-print-json_encode-php